# ZOOM IN and ZOOM OUT implementation in iOS app using phone gap and jQuery mobile

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing iOS application using phone gap.
I am using "canvas" for chart representation.
Now I want to implement ZOOM OUT and ZOOM IN functionality in canvas.
I am confused that in JQUERY MOBILE, Is there any function available for pinch in , pinch out event????? OR I have to use external library such like jGesture.js?

Friendly speaking , I don't want to use external library.But give me proper solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile does not include events for Zoom (pinch gestures).  I have an SVG app where I needed the same.  I ended up using the hammer.js library (http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/), handling the transformstart, transform, and transformend events.

The event object returns the current scale, so you can compare it with the previous scale to determine if you are zooming in or out.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have used event object that returns the current scale.